# Keypress event to duplicate div not working well

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/6mqcf6j6/

```
$(".start").on('keypress', function () {
        var zm1 = $(".start");
        zm1.removeAttr('class');
        var $new = $('#initial-input').clone();
        var count = $(".input-holder").length;
        $new.attr('id', "clone" + count)
        $new.find('input').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('name', 'name' + count).attr('id', 'name' + count).attr('class', 'start');
        });
        $('#input-wrapper').append($new);

    });
```

Why jquery still clone divs, although class attribute from first input is deleting?

While typing in first field, second div with two fields should be cloned one time, and while typing in second div, third should be cloned...

Thanks

Comment: is each field supposed to clone unlimited times?  Or just once per input(and once per subsequent clone)?

Comment: Can you post your HTML please. NB: Im aware it's on JSFiddle but still...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6mqcf6j6/1/ is this how you want it to act?

Comment: Andrew Coder, awesome! Is possible to clear new generated value? Bcoz now new generated input inherit value from first one.